# Internal table with header line

Tags: abap

We have class which process items from document in modul FI. I am trying Select data into Internal Table and after that count vat. But its raising error in declaration

```
DATA: IT_BSEG TYPE TABLE IT_VBSEG WITH HEADER LINE.

LOOP AT IT_BSEG.
  IT_VBSEG-FIELX = IT_VBSEG-FIELX + wa_x.
  modify IT_VBSEG. 
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ABAP OO you cannot use internal tables with header line. Try to modify your program using a field symbol:

```
DATA: IT_BSEG TYPE TABLE IT_VBSEG.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_bseg> like line of IT_BSEG.

LOOP AT IT_BSEG ASSIGNING <fs_bseg>.
  <fs_bseg>-FIELX = <fs_bseg>-FIELX + wa_x. 
ENDLOOP.
```